# Custom Map unmarshalling with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an XML which contains maps serialised like this:

```
<system>
  ...
  <entities>
    <entity>
      <string>key<string>
      <string><![CDATA[["a", "b", "c"]]]></string>
    </entity>
    ...
  </entities>
</system>
```

What I would like to get from this is that the `<entities>` are deserialised as  `Map<String, Object>` with `map.get(key)` returning a List of strings.

```
class System {
  ...
  private Map<String, Object> properties;
}
```

So the question is how do I make it work with JAXB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use an XmlAdapter and the @XmlJavaTypeAdapter annotation.

Step 1 : Create a class Entity that represents your `<entity>` element and map it with JAXB.

Step 2 : Create a class that extends `XmlAdapter<List<Entity>,Map<String,Object>` and define the abstracts methods marshall and unmarshall.

Step 3 : Create a class Entities like this :

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlSeeAlso({Entity.class})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Entities{

    @XmlElement(name="entity")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(YourAdapter.class)
    private Map<String,Object> yourMap;

    //getters, setters, and methods
}
```

Then when you unmarshall your file, you'll have an Entities object that contains your map.

Please tell me if you're encountering trouble, of if this solution does fits your needs, so i can edit/append my answer.

> EDIT :

If your Entities element is not your root element, then you can map it like this :

```
class ParentElement{

    //Other fields

    @XmlElement(name="entities")
    private Entities entities;

    //Getters, Setters, Methods
}
```

And keep the entities class

```
@XmlSeeAlso({Entity.class})
public class Entities{

    @XmlElement(name="entity")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(YourAdapter.class)
    private Map<String,Object> yourMap;

    //getters, setters, and methods
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the only problem I cannot wrap my head around is that <entities> is not an XmlRootElement, but rather just a member of bigger object. I'll update my original question.

Comment: I updated the answer, does it resolve your problem ?

Comment: Thank you, it didn't directly, but you certainly helped me to get on the right track. JAXB doesn't like \@XmlElementWrapper and \@XmlJavaTypeAdapter on the same property. I had to create another entity for collection.

Comment: Weird that Wrapper and Adapter doesn't work together, i'll look into it. Anyway, i updated the answer to what you probably used. Can you accept the answer if it is correct ? Thank you.

Comment: For the record, the specification allows the use of \@XmlElementWrapper and \@XmlJavaTypeAdapter , but a bug is currently present in JAXB that prevent us for doing it : https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-787